# Is it possible to create a VPN setting on the command line?

Tags: windows-7, vpn, netsh

I would like to perform the equivalent to the following steps but from the command line:

Control Panel / Network and Sharing Center / Set up a new connection or network

Wizard starts ->
Connect to a workplace / Create a new connection / Use my Internet connection (VPN) / IP Address and Destination Name, etc.

I think that I might be able to do this with something like **netsh** but I could really use some assistance in jump starting this.

Can anyone help, even if its only to tell me it can't be done that way ;-)

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use the Connection Manager Administration Kit (CMAK) to create a profile that can be distributed / installed in a silent mode on the client.

This is a nice screenshot walkthrough:

> http://www.isaserver.org/img/upl/vpnkitbeta2/cmak.htm