# Create VPN connection using batch

Tags: networking, vpn, batch, batch-file

Is there a way to make a batch file that creates a VPN connection?
I just need it to accept the Internet address and Destination name, and make a VPN based on that.

It'd also be great to get the batch file to edit the VPN if possible also. I need it to edit the connection settings to this:

[image]

And this to be unticked:

[image]

If someone can help me that'll be great.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to create a VPN setting on the command line?](http://superuser.com/questions/295581/is-it-possible-to-create-a-vpn-setting-on-the-command-line), also see [Change VPN in Windows 7 from command line](http://superuser.com/questions/412218/change-vpn-in-windows-7-from-command-line)

Comment: Is there a way to do it without CMAK?

Comment: If you'd like newer/different answers to the existing question, please earn a bit of [rep](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) and place a [bounty](http://superuser.com/help/bounty) on it (it should give you a chance to comment as to why you'd like more answers).

Comment: I would love if I can earn more rep and place a bounty on it, but right now I just need to be able to do this.